# Persistence for high mandatory level application - windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, persistence, uac

I'm writing application that needs to be run in high mandatory level and needs to run every time the OS is starting. I tried to put it in Run in registry and in Startup directory and it didnt run after a restart. Im doing this from C code using Winapi, the code is working, when Im using it with regular privileges apps it works normaly. I changed the "UAC Execution Level" option in the linker to highestAvailable.

How can I get the app running at high mandatory level every restart?

*Note: I dont try to bypass UAC or elevate to high privilege with exploit, I want it to be legitimate with UAC and run at every restart.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are asking "how can I have a program automatically run as `highestAvailable` at startup without waiting for the user's consent"?

Comment: No, I want it to be **with** the user's consent, I want it to be legitimate and prompt the UAC window and the user will need to press yes.
Its a legit app, not malware or something, I dont want to it bypass the UAC

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Comment: don't add manifest to your exe, register it, and relaunch self with `ShellExecuteEx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Create a service, or
- Configure Task Scheduler to create a logon app (example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/logon-trigger-example--c---)). The [IPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iprincipal) interface has a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iprincipal-put_runlevel) to set the admin requirement.

That way, you will register your app once with UAC prompt and then it will run each restart in elevated mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Can I do it only with a registry key or it doesnt support high mandatory apps with UAC?

Comment: @BlackMamba - the apps registered under `RunOnce` run at admin rights. but explorer will be wait until such app exit - so you need exec new copy of self from this and resore value of this key

Comment: @BlackMamba Why do you want to do it only with a registry key? Do you mind sharing the reason?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Its seems more easy and comfortable but I've already used the task scheduler to do it and it works. It was little hard and the code was long with the COM objects but it does the job.

Comment: @BlackMamba Thanks for sharing. Then you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answers your question.